# Server IP address not found

Tags: networking, ubuntu, apache-http-server

My goal is to allow a user to access a website that I have under development on my local web server.

The problem is that when a user comes into my LAN and lands on the website home page it functions as expected and returns the page, but any attempt to access directories or files below the web root results in “the requested URL was not found”, “servername IP address could not be found”.

Needless to say, it all works perfectly when just on my LAN and when accessing via external_IP_address/server_root but any attempt to access anything below this fails.

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and apache2. My local server has a fixed internal (192) address and no local DNS Server.

To clarify further.
The site is a WordPress site.
The user is external to my LAN and comes in via my outward facing fixed IP which is forwarded to my server on port 80. This work for the user landing on the homepage of the WordPress site but they cannot go any further.

The user can get to externalIP/site/index.php OK but fails if clicking on subsequent links that reference my local server name.
The problem appears to be that it tries to resolve my local server name which it cannot do. So, if I am correct, then I am looking for a workaround for this situation.

Comment: For answering you will need to give some configuration data. This is most likely a matter of permissions, but we do need to know user accounts used locally and externally and server configuration.

Comment: I assume (1) you're talking about a user external to your LAN and (2) you're talking about following links (to subordinate pages) from your site's home page.  (3) Please show us what your `<a href="..."> elements look like.  (4) If you tell your user "you should see the page at "(site)/foo/bar.html", can they go directly to that?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using absolute URLs in your links. You can make relative ones (skip the server part): `<a href="/some/other/part.html">`